# Calculate the integral of the function only with the immediate integrals

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to calculate this indefinite integral:

$$
\int{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}}dx
$$

I realized that the technique to solve is to "transform" the numerator equal to the denominator of the fraction so I tried this:

$$
\int{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}}dx = \int{\frac{(x^2-1)+2}{x^2+1}}dx = \int{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}}dx + \int{\frac{2}{x^2+1}}dx
$$

My problem is that my equation is returning to the original problem!The book suggests the following resolution , but why it appears this integral dx?
$$
\int{\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}}dx = \int{\frac{(x^2-1)-2}{x^2+1}}dx = \int dx - \int{\frac{2}{x^2+1}}dx = x - 2\int{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}dx = x - 2arctanx + c
$$

Comment: There is already a mistake in your first line where you replace in the numerator $x^2-1$ by $(x^2-1)+2$

Comment: @imranfat, $(x^2+1)-2$ :)

Comment: That is what it should be indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using long-division on your rational expression:

$$\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}=\frac{(x^2+1)-2}{x^2+1}=1-\frac{2}{x^2+1}$$

So now we can integrate the $1$ (that is, $\int 1\ dx$), and subtract the integral of $\frac{2}{x^2+1}$ (which is $2\arctan(x)+C$).

Whenever you have a rational function whose numerator's degree is not smaller than its denominator's, a good first step is to do polynomial long-division.